# div on the flash movie

Tags: flash, stack-overflow

elgg.in/works/momslingolougne/ this is the working link.

My problem is here when we enter the login section . that time show a popup window. but ther is girl vector image . that is fglash file. the flash file is overlapping the popup div. i have tried wmode="transparent" and position:absolute; z-index:0

but not working.

Answer (score 0):

By default most browsers embed Flash content at the top most layer.

Try this [Flash behind HTML guide](http://capcai.indorelation.com/blog/index.php/2006/02/22/flash-behind-html/)